# wash sale with leveraged ETF

Tags: united-states, etf, irs, wash-sale, leveraged-etf

If a person sales regular ETF ( suppose QQQ) at a loss and buys a leveraged ETF on similar Index e.g TQQQ within 30 days, will the loss on QQQ be treated as wash sale ?

Answer (score 1):

There's not a crystal clear definition of "substantially identical" securities, but I would strongly suspect that an ETF and a leveraged ETF, even on the same index, would *not* be considered "substantially identical". In fact, [it is arguable](https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/investment-products/etf/tax-rules-for-losses-etfs) that buying an ETF from a different provider that tracks the same index would avoid the wash-sale rules since the aim could be to pay less fees, have less tracking error, etc. (stocks would not apply because there is no practical difference between buying a stock from one broker versus another)

So you would probably be safe not reporting the sale as a wash sale and realizing your loss, but in the end it's up to the IRS to determine if your loss should be deferred.

(p.s. at worst, a wash sale would *defer* the loss until you sold the leveraged ETF, so if you did it in the same tax year it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  If you are worried about it, buy a similar leveraged ETF other than TQQQ or futures (/NQ, /MNQ).

Edit: Wash sale rules do not apply to futures.  Since the OP has a taxable account, trading futures might be an alternative.

[How Are Futures and Options Taxed?](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/active-trading/061015/how-are-futures-options-taxed.asp)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).